# How am I supposed to use double-ended driver bits in a magnetic extension?

Tags: powertools, screwdriver

My impact driver is probably my most used tool for home DIY tasks. I have a corresponding set of bits that are very useful. Two of them, however, are a bit confusing to me:

[image]
[image]

They are double sided. If I place one end in the bit holder as shown in the bottom photo, it's very wobbly. How are these meant to be used?

Thanks!

Comment: Notice how all three of those bits have the same back end? That depression is designed to fit the tool's retainer. They're not intended to be stacked.

Answer (score 4):

Very simple: *Don't put them in the bit holder*.

The bit holder has two uses:

- Allow use of short bits

  The double-ended bits are long enough that they don't need a holder.
- Allow easy change of bits

  The double-ended bits each give you two bits in one. Loosen, flip, tighten.

You should make sure the bits are designed for impact drivers - some are, some are designed only for use in ordinary drill/drivers.

Comment: Regarding the second part of what you said, I'm almost certain it's fine to use these in the impact mode (I don't think my impact driver has a non-impact mode). They came in a set clearly labelled "impact duty". Similar: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Milwaukee-SHOCKWAVE-Impact-Duty-Alloy-Steel-Screw-Driver-Bit-Set-74-Piece-48-32-4062/300844425

Comment: I've never seen an "impact driver" that didn't have a non-impact mode. Using ordinary screwdriver bits in impact mode, even if technically OK, will wear them out faster and mess up the stuff you're working on too. Take a look on your tool for a switch (other than the power and forward/reverse switches).

Comment: There's the forward/reverse/neither switch. 1,2,3 buttons for torque limiting and a special mode for driving self-drilling screws. Makes sense about not using regular bits in impact mode. As mentioned above, I think these ARE impact bits.

Comment: I have worked the heck out of a double ended bit with an impact driver. A #3 phillips bit. driving self drilling tapping 14ga screws through 3/4" plywood into 14ga metal by the hundreds. They really last, at least the brand I had They are not meant to be used with a bit holder....

Comment: Milwaukee 2853: https://www.milwaukeetool.com/Products/Power-Tools/Fastening/Impact-Drivers/2853-20

Comment: Here's the box the bits came in: https://imgur.com/a/LmPrJQu. Impact Duty. Could you remove the part about them being screwdriver bits (or explain why you still think that's the case)?

Comment: A) I've never seen an impact driver _with_ a "non-impact" mode. B) AIUI, all these hex-shank bits are designed for use in an impact driver, whether the package says so or not. Frankly, hex shanks are a PITA to use is a regular 3-jaw chuck. C) There's a 3rd use for the bit holder - as an extension to get the bit into tight spaces

Comment: Oh, +1 for the "don't do this", BTW. ;)

Comment: @FreeMan I was getting confused between hammer drills, impact drivers and other tools. I have been corrected...

Comment: No worries! I've seen several brands of impact drivers and had never seen the "no impact" setting. I was going to ask what brand you used. :)

Comment: Hex shanks are fine in a regular 3-jaw chuck if you use a magnetic extension - I use them all the time.